# Android checkbox selection in listivew

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

In my android application I am storing all the details of contact list in mobile to a listview and a checkbox is added to it for selecting a particular contact.. but there is some problem in selecting checkbox, app is crashing while selecting I am giving the code below.. if anyone can help please help

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int count = listView.getCount();



                for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) listView.getChildAt(i);
                    checkBox = ((CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.selected));

                    if(checkBox.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(SendMessagesActivity.this, "How are u", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }


            }
        });
```

ContactsAdapter

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    SparseBooleanArray sba=new SparseBooleanArray();

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.contacts = contacts;

    }




    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;
        final ViewHolder mHolder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, null);
            mHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mHolder.textName     =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mHolder.textMobile   =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            mHolder.textSelector =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);



            convertView.setTag(mHolder);   


            }  


        else
        {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        mHolder.textMobile.setText(contacts.get(position).getMobile());
        mHolder.textName.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        mHolder.textName.setSelected(true);
        mHolder.textSelector.setChecked(sba.get(position));

        mHolder.textSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 if(mHolder.textSelector.isChecked())
                 {
                     sba.put(position, true);
                 }

                else
                {
                    sba.put(position, false);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }




    private class ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView textMobile,textName;
        private CheckBox textSelector;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide the logcat also

Comment: share your adapter class also you will get better options to do this

Comment: @ warlock and @ pavan .. Please check I added the adapter class also

Comment: ok the thing now is you want selected items right

Comment: yes....but when I am giving the first code it is crashing in mobile phone... but in emulator it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In your Contact Adapter, you will need to implement the check/uncheck, and make changes in arraylist of contact accordingly,

So on button click just get value from Adpater and see which all are checked.

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html This is the example I found on internet. check it

Answer (score 0):

you can do by following

1.put one boolean variable in your  Contact class

2.where is your implemented  check listener just that position set flag for your boolean variable true/false.

3.Now where you want selected item just add for loop for your  ArrayList contacts and check on boolean variable here you dont need to get views from list view and check.

if you have any query feel free to ask